# .Net web.config add GMT offset to web.config file

Tags: .net, datetime, web-config

I am currently building a web app that is for Australian based users but the server is not in Australia so the time-zone is incorrect. Is there type of entry I can add to the web.config file to offset the time on the server by GMT+10:00 ?

EDIT:

More to the point is there any way of setting this application-wide, it doesn't necessarily have to be in the web.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you need to do is to store your DateTime values as UTC instead of GMT.

There is a lot of related questions on SO:

- [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices)
- [Converting DateTime + TimeZone to UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595706/converting-datetime-timezone-to-utc)
- [Storing date/times as UTC in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580478/storing-date-times-as-utc-in-database)

Comment: I think it's something I need to be wary of in the future as it seems you can't do this easily, due to other circumstances I ended up moving the hosting to an Australian provider so I dodged a bullet this time, but next time I will set up a DateTime helper that I use everywhere to ensure that I don't run across this problem in the future